# Justification of using LH rule in this instance

Tags: calculus, limits

I was wondering how i can justify using L'hospital rule in this case to find the limit:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{\int_{t_{0}}^t q(t)e^{\int p(t)dt}dt}{e^{\int p(t)dt}}$$

It is given than $q$ and $p$ are differentiable and continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $p(t) \ge K > 0$ on $[t_{0}, \infty)$ and $q(t) \ge C > 0$ on $[t_{0}, \infty)$ for some positive constants $K$, $C$ and some time $t_{0}$ in $(- \infty, \infty)$.

Edit: It's also provided that $\frac{q(t)}{p(t)}$ tends to M which lies in (−∞,∞)

Comment: You have to know that $\frac {q(t)} {p(t)}$ has a limit.

Comment: ah yes, it's been provided in the question, it tends to  M which lies in $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: Then you can apply L'Hopital's Rule and the answer is $M$.

Comment: @geetha290krm i know that, but doesn't L'Hospital requires the expression to be an indeterminate form of either $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ , how do i know if the expression in that instance comes to that form

Comment: $p(t)\geq K>0$ implies $\int_{t_0}^{t} p(s)ds \to \infty$ as $ t \to \infty$.

Comment: i see, thank you!

Comment: I struggle with the notation, I think. Is $e^{\int p(t)\mathrm{d}t}=\exp(\int p\mathrm{d}\lambda)$ the exponential of the integral over $p$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure? It seems that you share a different understanding.

Comment: @Matija
you are right, it's exponential of integral of p. It's actually the integrating factor i get after solving a liner D.E which is $y' + p(t)y = q(t)$. the whole expression : $$\frac{\int_{t_{0}}^t q(t)e^{\int p(t)dt}}{e^{\int p(t)dt}}$$ is actually just y(t). Originally i was asked to find the limit of y(t) when $t$ tends to infinity.

Comment: The integral $\int p(t)\mathrm dt$ is either $\infty$ or not defined, according to your argumentation, since $p(t)\ge K>0$ for $t\ge t_0$, right? I also do not understand the integral $\int_{t_0}^tq(t)$, because the differential is missing, say $\mathrm d s$, from my perspective, and also since $q$ only depends on $t$ (which is the upper bound for the integral, hence we don't integrate with respect to $t$), so the integral in the nominator seems to be over a constant function. That's my understanding, but this cannot be right, right?

Comment: @Matija oh noo i forgot to add dt for q(t), i didn't realise. I am so sorry . To be honest there are of lot errors which may have caused confusion. Yes q(t) is not a constant function

Comment: Looking at the question and the answer by Lutz, does the expression
$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\int_{t_0}^tq(s)e^{\int_{t_0}^sp(r)\mathrm{d}r}\mathrm{d}s}{e^{\int_{t_0}^tp(s)\mathrm{d}s}}$ look wrong to you?

Comment: @Matija this looks alright to me, although the limits over the exponential integrals weren't necessary, as the arbitrary constant that may appear from them cancels out. I hope I didn't waste too much of your time

Comment: You shouldn't use $t$ as both one of your limits of integration as well as your dummy variable of integration, that leads to a lot of confusion

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful to avoid using the same variable in different roles, and to remove ambiguity. So select one primitive $P(t)=\int p(t)\,dt$. Then the expression in question is
$$
\frac{\int_{t_0}^tq(s)e^{P(s)}\,ds}{e^{P(t)}}.
$$
The quotient of the derivatives is consequently
$$
\frac{q(t)e^{P(t)}}{p(t)e^{P(t)}}=\frac{q(t)}{p(t)},
$$
to which you now apply the assumptions of the task.

Comment: I think there is a typo, do you mean $P(t)=\int_c^{t}p(s)\mathrm{d}s$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ (maybe $c\in(-\infty,t_0]$)? Also, I do not see an answer to the question how the application of l'Hôpital's rule is justified...

Comment: As in the end $q$ has the size $KM$, the limit is indeed of the form $\frac∞∞$, so that indeed the corresponding variant of l'Hopital applies.